# v.in.ogr does not provide any error information

Tags: grass-gis, ogr, error, command-line, docker

I am using the `mundialis/grass-py3-pdal:8.2.0-alpine` docker image to run GRASS. I run the following from the bash command line (inside the container):

```
/usr/local/grass/bin/v.in.ogr input=/path/to/nonexistent/folder/and/file.shp output=/another/nonexistent/path
```

... and I get back no output. The script just runs and finishes. No complaint. Nothing.

So I try it in verbose mode, with an existing output folder:

```
/usr/local/grass/bin/v.in.ogr --verbose input=/path/to/nonexistent/folder/and/file.shp output=/output
```

Still no complaint. Needless to say, there's also nothing in the output folder.

What's going on here? Is there a way I can get the script to give me more information? As I've never used this script, I'm sort of hoping to have some google-able error messages if possible.

====

EDIT #1: I verified that when I do `ls /usr/local/grass/bin/v.in.ogr` from inside the container, I get a listing of the script, which is shown in a nice, executable green font. So the script seems to be running. It's just being very, very quiet when things go wrong.

====

EDIT #2: I also verified with a `touch` that I have the rights to write to the output folder. So it's not that.

====

EDIT #3: I simplified the situation above somewhat to make the question easier to answer. The full command for running the script with a real file is `docker-compose run --rm grass-service /usr/local/grass/bin/v.in.ogr --verbose input=/input/kx-amtrak-stations-SHP/amtrak-stations.shp output=/output/grass_map`. This is also failing silently, though I get a status of 0 rather than a status of 1. The `output` folder is set to `rw` in my `docker-compose.yml` file, which looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  grass-service:
    image: mundialis/grass-py3-pdal:8.2.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./output:/output:rw # This will be the persistent store
      - ./src:/src:rw # Contains code to run analysis
      - ./input:/input # Contains some .tif images to import
    environment:
      - STAGE=dev
      - GISDBASE=/data/grassdata
      - LOCATION=2193
      - MAPSET=project
      - LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
      - LANG=C.UTF-8
      - ADDITIONAL_PATH=/usr/local/grass/bin
    network_mode: host
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

... and the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mundialis/grass-py3-pdal:8.2.0-alpine
RUN export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/grass/bin
RUN chmod +x /src/fulltask.sh
RUN chmod +w /output
```

Comment: Are you sure you're mounting your data paths correctly? The Docker container won't see paths on your host unless you allow it to do so. I'd try do something like `ogrinfo -so /path/to.shp` to check the data from inside the container.

Comment: @alphabetasoup thanks for your comment. In my case, I *know* that the path is wrong. I'm thinking about opening a pull request to change the behavior so that -- at least in verbose mode -- the script complains loudly when the path isn't valid. Failing silently is not normal behavior

Comment: It may fail silently with a non-zero status, which is still some form of information

Comment: Oh yes, that's a great point

Comment: Well, it appears that I only get a status code of 1, which is the generic status code for failure. So that's not terribly helpful. I would expect more output with the `--verbose` tag applied

Comment: I'm still a bit confused by this. You know that the input doesn't exist, and so you expect it not to work, but you're wondering why you're not getting an error message that describes that the file doesn't exist? I get that's an annoying limitation, but I'm not really seeing why it's such a huge issue. I often do things like `os.path.exists()` in Python to check whether an input exists.

Comment: Also, what is your _actual_ command? `v.ogr.in` expects the output to be in a GRASS environment; when I use this same Docker container I do `grass -c /path/to/input.gpkg -e /grassdata && grass /grassdata/mapset/ --exec v.in.ogr --verbose input=/path/to/input.gpkg output=label` Notably, the `output=label` is not a path, it's the name of a GRASS dataset that will be managed by GRASS within `/grassdata/mapset`. Please include your actual code.

Comment: Thanks. I've added some more detail to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can import a file using `v.in.ogr` you first have to create a GRASS environment: a *database*, *location*, and *mapset*. I use this same Docker container (in conjunction with some [workflow software](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) and I precede the import statement with `grass -c {file} -e {grass-database}`:

```bash
GRASSDATA=/output/grassdata && \
MAPSET=PERMANENT && \
MAP=amtrak-stations && \
mkdir -p $GRASSDATA && \
(grass -c /input/kx-amtrak-stations-SHP/amtrak-stations.shp -e $GRASSDATA && \
grass $GRASSDATA/$MAPSET/ --exec v.in.ogr --verbose --overwrite input=/input/kx-amtrak-stations-SHP/amtrak-stations.shp output=$MAP snap=0.0001) 2>&1 | tee /output/logfile
```

The first grass command creates the environment necessary to run other GRASS commands, which is necessary to establish a region, projection, etc. In this case it's created on the basis of the input that is imported in the second grass command, which is run using `--exec` so that it is a standalone shell command that does not need to be run in an interactive GRASS session.

Lastly it's wrapped in brackets and stdout/stderr are piped to `tee` to be written in a log file. This should allow you to both see any output on the terminal, but also have it written to a file; it may be that Docker is swallowing your stderr which is why you can't see any error output.

GRASS's idioms are tricky, I recommend doing some [introductory GRASS tutorials](https://baharmon.github.io/intro-to-grass) but noting that with a Docker container this idiom of using `--exec` is very useful.

Note especially that the `output` of `v.in.ogr` is not a path.